# Python - Pcapy to Scapy on SPAN port, odd behaviour

Tags: python, scapy

I built a network sniffer in Scapy but it can't handle the rate of packets I am sniffing (it adds 15-20 minutes of latency which is just unacceptable). I have used Pcapy before in the past at this speed with success, but this time to save me having to re-write all my parsing code that uses Scapy, I want to convert a packet received by Pcapy into a Scapy IP object. The problem is when I try to do this, the IP's and protocol numbers I get are scrambled/unusable, like Scapy is reading the wrong section of the packet.

Some example code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pcapy import findalldevs, open_live
from impacket import ImpactDecoder, ImpactPacket
from scapy.all import *

def sniff():
    interface = "eth3"

    print "Listening on: %s" % interface

    # Open a live capture
    reader = open_live(interface, 65535, 1, 100)

    # Set a filter to be notified only for TCP packets
    reader.setfilter('ip proto \\tcp')

    # Run the packet capture loop
    reader.loop(0, callback)

def callback(hdr, data):

    pkt = IP(data)
    if IP in pkt:

        print pkt[IP].dst

    # Parse the Ethernet packet
    #decoder = ImpactDecoder.EthDecoder()
    #ether = decoder.decode(data)

    # Parse the IP packet inside the Ethernet packet
    #iphdr = ether.child()

    # Parse the TCP packet inside the IP packet
    #tcphdr = iphdr.child()

    # Only process SYN packets
    #if tcphdr.get_SYN() and not tcphdr.get_ACK():

    #    # Get the source and destination IP addresses
    #    src_ip = iphdr.get_ip_src()
    #    dst_ip = iphdr.get_ip_dst()

    #    # Print the results
    #    print "Connection attempt %s -> %s" % (src_ip, dst_ip)

def main():
    sniff()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And an example of the output:

```
30.184.113.84
0.120.231.205
30.184.113.91
5.64.113.97
0.120.231.206
21.248.113.98
0.120.231.207
0.120.231.208
0.120.231.209
0.120.231.210
0.120.231.211
0.48.243.73
```

As you can see these IP's dont make sense, where do you think I am going wrong. Eth3 is connected to a NetGear mirror port.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, just me being an idiot, I blame bank-holiday Mondays. I was trying to detect the packet from the wrong layer. Convert raw to Ether and Scapy does the rest of the work for me.

```
def callback(hdr, data):

    pkt = Ether(data)

    if IP in pkt:

        print pkt[IP].dst
    else:

        print list(pkt)
```

Cheers